# Mostrar mensaje desde trigger en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

En PostgresSQL yo podía levantar excepciones desde un trigger con el Raise Exception, por eso pregunto: ¿cómo puedo mostrar un mensaje desde un trigger como lo hacía en Postgres con el Raise Exception en MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Pon este texto y saldra un mensaje

```
DECLARE
  msg VARCHAR(255);

SET msg = CONCAT('La fecha no puede ser anterior a ', NOW());
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = msg;
```